# css @font-face rule inconsistency

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, raspberry-pi

I'm hosting a small web server on a raspberry pi, and I'm witnessing some inconsistency with the @font-face rule. In my webpage I have a simple javascript clock borrowed from W3Schools:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script>
            function startTime() {
                var today = new Date();
                var h = today.getHours();
                var m = today.getMinutes();
                m = checkTime(m);
                document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = h + ":" + m ;
                var t = setTimeout(function() {
                    startTime()
                }, 500);
            }

            function checkTime(i) {
                if (i < 10) {
                    i = "0" + i
                };// add zero in front of numbers < 10
                return i;
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="startTime()">

        <div id="clock"></div>

    </body>

</html>
```

I then try to style the clock with the @fontface property:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'roboto-thin';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
    src: url('res/roboto-thin.woff2') format('woff2');
}
#clock{
    font-family: 'roboto-thin';
    font-size: 100px;
    color:#f1f1f1;
    float: right;
}
```

The problem I have is that the font renders perfectly on my laptop in Chrome and on my desktop in Chrome, but curiously on my RPi chromium doesn't download the font (I've checked in the developer panel), and replaces it with big ugly Arial. The same happens in Firefox and in IE on my laptop and desktop, although IE probably just doesn't support Woff2.

Is there anyone out there who knows why this is happening?

Thank you for reading this,

Dylan

Comment: does chromium show that it's trying to load the font but then gives up (network tab in the dev tools) or does it not even do anything with that. Have you tried a different browser on the pi? (which OS is it running?)

Comment: See http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff2 and isolate your problem – it is probably entirely irrelevant that you are using a clock from the w3fools site, test with *normal text* first.

Comment: Does the font download if you right click or hover over the text when using the Pi? Searching I see bugs in older version of Chromium that sound just like this. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336476

Comment: Hi thanks for the answers, no chromium doesn't even attempt to download the fonts, and I already read about that bug in chromium, it's not that. I mentioned the javascript because I thought it might be interfering with the css. I'll hav a look at that link in the morning, I need to have a sleep :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in fact it seems that chromium on the Raspberry Pi doesn't support Woff2 fonts, I used FontSquirrel and got a font kit and now it works perfectly. Thanks Jukka for pointing me in the right direction.